# How to optimize a N+1 with a calculated attributed on model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord, active-model-serializers

I'm using Active model Serializers. I've a model which has

```
class Item
  has_many :order_items
  has_many :orders, through: :order_items

  def number_in_stock
    in_use_count = order_items.joins(:orders)
                                     .where('orders.status = ?', 'in_use')
                                     .sum('houses_item.quantity')

    quantity - in_use_count
  end
```

The problem is that I've N+1 queries when serializing a collection of items:

```
# Serializer
ItemSerializer < Base serializer
   attribute :number_in_stock

# Controller
render json: @items
```

How I can resolve this N+1 query issue?

Comment: Please include an example of your models, schema and the expected result.

Comment: The answer here is most likely something like`Item.joins(:orders).select('items.*', 'SUM(orders.some_column) AS in_use_count' ).group(:id)` but its impossible to answer the question properly without more info.

Comment: @Arnold Roa Please provide proper description with the model, controller and serializers